# How to inject video into a live stream?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, live, vlc, rtmp

When you have two or more live streams, and you want the ability to toggle between the two,  such as switching to camera 2's feed on the main screen, how do you do that and what do you need to consider when constructing such a system?

I prefer to do this programmatically via the command line or python, etc. and have been experimenting with combinations of VLC, nginx rtmp, and ffmpeg but I'm missing a key concept. Is the correct term for this video stream injecting?